# How do we show that $x^5y^3 + x^4y^4 + x^3y^5$ is $\Omega(x^3y^3)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Basically I'm wondering how I can show that $x^5y^3 + x^4y^4 + x^3y^5$ is $\Omega(x^3y^3)$.  Any ideas?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jenna, please use $ sign for equations.

Comment: For $\Omega$ you need to say where the variables are going.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the expression in the OP $F(x,y)$. For any $x,y >0 \ F(x,y) \geq 3 x^3 y^3 = \Omega (x^3 y^3)$

EDIT: $F(x,y) \geq x^3y^3 + x^3 y^3 + x^3 y^3 = 3 x^3 y^3 = \Omega(x^3 y^3)$ since $x^5>x^4>x^3$. Same with $y$.

Comment: How is this proving it?

Comment: Here, $x,y > 1$ is assumed.  @JennaMagic If this does not match your desired conditions on $x,y$, you'll need to state what your conditions are.  For example, is $y=-x$ or $y=1/x$ possible?

Comment: This is an asymptotic result, i.e. if $x,y$ can be taken arbitrarily large, but this is a condition for using big-Oh notation

Comment: The inequality holds for $x,y\geqslant1$, not $x,y\gt0$.